# WebSphere MQ Channel Access Security Questions

Tags: ibm-mq

Consider the following queue defintinons:

> SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,CONNECT)
>
> SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,GET)
>
> SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,PUT)
>
> DEFINE CHANNEL ($cname) CHLTYPE (SVRCONN) TRPTYPE (TCP) MCAUSER('tcs-mq-user') REPLACE
>
> SET CHLAUTH($cname) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) MCAUSER('tcs-mq-user')

1. What is the meaning of MCAUSER in both DEFINE CHANNEL and SETCHLAUTH?
2. Should tcs-mq-user belong to mq-user group?
3. Does this mean only tcs-mq-user has access to the queue manager in bindings mode? Now what if I want to give access to another user in the binding mode, should I create another pair of DEFINE CHANNEL and SET CHLAUTH commands for this user?
4. Is it possible to give the channel access to the mcs-user group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, answers are on sale, buy one get three free today!  :-)  Let's take these in order...

**1.A.** The channel's MCAUSER value is the ID against which authorization checks are performed. If the `DEFINE CHL() CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)` leaves MCAUSER blank, then clients connecting can specify the ID that they wish to connect as.  If they fail to specify, WMQ client *attempts* to use the ID of the client user as seen from the workstation where the client app is running and present that.  Setting `MCAUSER` in the channel definition prevents the client app from specifying the value.

**1.B.** The MCAUSER in an `ADDRESSMAP` rule is used to map the `MCAUSER` based on some identifying criteria.  It says "**IF** a connection arrives on *this channel* with a specified IP address | User Name | SSL Distinguished Name **THEN** use *this* ID as the `MCAUSER` **AND** allow the channel to run if no other rules block it.

The recommendation if a `CHLAUTH` mapping rule is used is usually to set the channel's `MCAUSER` to a value that cannot possibly be a user ID so it will not run.  This way the channel defaults to a secure state unless a `CHLAUTH` rule overrides the MCAUSER to a value intended to allow access.  The quintessential value for `MCAUSER` used to be `nobody` until Mark Taylor, WMQ Strategist from the Hursley Lab, suggested using a value that can not be an actual user ID, such as `no#body`.  As of WMQ V7.1 the value `*NOACCESS` is a reserved work and what I'm using in the conference presentations these days.

**2.** Yes.  WMQ authorizes based on groups.  The standard advice is to deconstruct your security requirements into roles like 'admin', 'app1', 'app2', 'monitoring', 'anonymous', etc.  Then for each of these roles that requires access, create a group.

But access requests come from principals that are uniquely identified, not from groups. The authorization check requires an account to check against so the MCAUSER in the channel is an ID while the authorization rights are stored by group.  To associate a user with the correct rights, enroll them in the right group.

This is standard UNIX authorization model that supports separation of duties.  Resource admins (the WMQ administrator) authorize groups.  Account admins enroll user IDs in groups.  It takes both groups to provide access.  In the real world, most shops do not utilize the separation of duties feature but in a significant cases it is mandatory.

**3.** Sort of.  A default QMgr at V7.1 or higher won't allow any remote connections at all.  This is because when created it has no `AUTHREC` rules so non-admins are not granted access.  Admins are blocked from remote access by the default `CHLAUTH` rule.

With the rules specified, *anyone* can successfully connect to the `$cname` channel and will be authorized as `tcs-mq-user`.  If you want them to connect as a different user ID *with the same privileges* then you would need to add that ID to the `mq-user` group and then set the channel up to map the IDs presented.  If you wanted to *enforce* which ID someone connected as you'd have to specify the mapping by IP address or, better yet, based on their certificate distinguished name.

**4.** No.  As noted in #2 above, access requests are always made by principals, not by groups.  The whole point of `CHLAUTH` rules, `MCAUSER` and distinguished name mapping is to resolve the user ID that the channel uses for authorization checks.  The channel definition's `MCAUSER` is a security control in that ID resolution process and so it operates on the ID and not on the group.

If you haven't already found the site, you might find [T-Rob.net](http://t-rob.net) useful.  In particular, on the Links page I have posted all the WMQ Security presentations from the conferences as well as links to my and other authors' articles.

Comment: As always very throrough answer. As for item 3 on your answer, you say *anyone* can connect to $cname... Now I understand this from a client mode. How about bindings mode, is this true there as well?

Comment: in the bindings, or shared memory mode, I need to switch to tcs-mq-user right? What if tcs-mq-user is a non-login id?

Comment: In bindings mode, no channel is used.  It is a direct memory-to-memory connection.  The CHLAUTH rules and channel definition apply only when the connection is made through the network stack.  If you want tcs-mq-user to connect in bindings mode, that ID must be capable of running a process.  So, depending on what "non-login" means in your shop you may need to make it a login account to run processes locally. (Some shops configure "non-login" such that interactive shells are disallowed but root can still start a process running as that ID.  Your mileage may vary.)